# How to only print certain text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull some financial data for city governments using BeautifulSoup (had to convert the files from pdf). I just want to get the data as a csv file and then I'll analyze it in Excel or SAS. My problem is that I do not want to print the "& nbsp;" that is in the original HTML, just the numbers and the row heading. Any suggestions on how I can do this without using regex?

Below is a sample of the html I am looking at. Next is my code (currently just in proof of concept mode, need to prove I can get clean data before moving on). New to Python and programming so any help is appreciated.

```
<TD class="td1629">Investments (Note 2)</TD>

<TD class="td1605">&nbsp;</TD>

<TD class="td479">&nbsp;</TD>

<TD class="td1639">-</TD>

<TD class="td386">&nbsp;</TD>

<TD class="td116">&nbsp;</TD>

<TD class="td1634">2,207,592</TD>

<TD class="td479">&nbsp;</TD>

<TD class="td1605">&nbsp;</TD>

<TD class="td1580">2,207,592</TD>

<TD class="td301">&nbsp;</TD>

<TD class="td388">&nbsp;</TD>

<TD class="td1637">2,882,018</TD>
```

CODE

```
import htmllib
import urllib
import urllib2
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

CAFR = open("C:/Users/snown/Documents/CAFR2004 BFS Statement of Net Assets.html", "r")

soup = BeautifulSoup(CAFR)

assets_table = soup.find(True, id="page_27").find(True, id="id_1").find('table') 

rows = assets_table.findAll('tr')    
for tr in rows:    
  cols = tr.findAll('td')    
  for td in cols:    
    text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
    print text+"|",    
  print
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
```

It converts `&nbsp;` and other html entities to appropriate characters.

To write it to a csv file:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> csv_file = sys.stdout
>>> writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter="|")
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<tr><td>1<td>&nbsp;<td>3",
...                      convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
>>> writer.writerows([''.join(t.encode('utf-8') for t in td(text=True))
...                   for td in tr('td')] for tr in soup('tr'))
1| |3
```

I've used `t.encode('utf-8')` due to `&nbsp;` is translated to non-ascii `U+00A0` (no-break space) character.

Comment: very cool, thank you @Sebastian. to go one step farther, is there a way to write the output so it is 1|3 instead of 1| |3?

Comment: @snown: just don't add columns that contain only space. To check whether there are non-space characters in a string: `if column.strip()`. Method `strip()` on Unicode strings understands no-break space as a space and it removes it from the string.